# Is $\frac{p}{2(p+1)} +\frac{q}{2(q+1)} + \frac{r}{2(r+1)} < 1$ equivalent to $\frac{1}{p+1} +\frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{r+1} > 1 $?

Tags: inequality

I am reading section 2 of the paper *Coxeter Functors and Gabriel's Theorem*  where the following inequalities arise in the proof of proposition 2.1,
\begin{align}
\frac{p}{2(p+1)} +\frac{q}{2(q+1)} + \frac{r}{2(r+1)} &< 1 &(1)\\
\frac{1}{p+1} +\frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{r+1} &> 1 &(2)
\end{align}

How do I show that these inequalites are equivalent for natural numbers $p,q,r$?

I tried inverting $(1)$ to obtain $(2)$ but was unsuccessful in my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{p+1}=1-2\cdot\dfrac p{2(p+1)}$$